# Can I create a website with no-profit at the moment with the F-2 visa status?

Tags: usa, immigration, student-visa, greencard, work-permit

Consider a person comes to the US with an F-2 visa status and has a plan to get his/her green card in the next year, but at the moment he/she likes to start a commercial website or mobile app but for free, up to he/she could get his/her green card.

Is it legal for him/her and won't cause a problem for him/his green card in the future?

PS: By a free commercial website/mobile app I mean something like websites/applications those offer a free access for a period of time(Free trial), or offer a free access to some basic utilities(and charge users for money for premium access). Or games those are free but charge users for money for extra coins/points/etc.).

Can an F-2 visa holder start the business for free, then after he/she gets his/her green card/ he/she starts the post trial/premium part of the business as well?

Comment: Most businesses don't generate profits when begun; time and effort is required to achieve market penetration, and customer knowledge, and customer engagement. Thus, setting up and running a website that can later be turned into a profit center sounds like "work" to me.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: But how can they proof that do I have an intention to make it profitable in future or just keep it as non-profitable?

Comment: They don't have to prove anything. If they see that activity, and they don't like it, they just cancel your visa.

Comment: To be safe, you can develop your website but do not release it to the public until you get your visa.